# React.js Jest: Test suite failed to run - [closed/Resolved]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I can't run npm test due to error:

● Test suite failed to run

```
/home/nrl/repo/frontend/node_modules/react-router-dom/es/Link.js:11
import React from 'react';
       ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Here is my test file.

```
import React from 'react';

import { Footer } from "../components/Footer";

function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(sum(1, 2)).toEqual(3);
});
```

This is Footer.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Link from "react-router-dom/es/Link"

export const Footer = () =>{
    return(
        <footer>
             ...
        </footer>
    )
};
```

Problem seems like about react-router-dom/es/Link. 
Because it fixes if I remove import Link line from footer.js file.
Can't I test components like this ?

Comment: check your paths, it should be some typo error.
For example, in the next lines, u missed semicolons at the end of lines: 

import React from 'react' (HERE SEMICOLON)
import Link from "react-router-dom/es/Link" (HERE SEMICOLON)

Comment: it runs perfect except npm test. i dont think so it is about typo.

Comment: Your issue comes from config, do you have `babel-jest` setup

Comment: delete your `node_modules` folder and install them again `npm install`

Comment: @klugjo I do not have babel-jest and .babelrc file. I created my app with create-react-app.

Comment: @Ikram-Ud-Daula I tried that several times but did not work unfortunately.

Comment: in your `package.json` you may find `extract-text-webpack-plugin` tell me which version is it is?

Comment: @Ikram-Ud-Daula I do not have that package too. Do I have to install it ?

Comment: you may find it in your project root or run `npm run eject` on your prompt then it generate a `package.json` file.

Comment: No, I mean I have package.json but there is no "extract-text-webpack-plugin" plugin listed. 
Here is my package.json:
https://gist.github.com/nurulmac11/aca98c1a6ca0048a2f334091044fff7d

Comment: please see previous cmment. i have made changes and before run`eject` you must commit your changes

Comment: Yes, I run 'npm run eject' command and I changed my package.json content and edited the same link the previous one. But same error still continues.

Comment: replace version with this `"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0"` and delete your `node_modules` folder and install again.

Comment: I tried it but still same error occurs.

Comment: can you show your `webpack.config.dev.js` file  that's may be `config\...` location

Comment: https://gist.github.com/nurulmac11/aaecdb60ced303042c1a1ef6b9a95a3d

Comment: change on Footer.js file to `import {Link} from "react-router-dom"` instead `import Link from "react-router-dom/es/Link"`

Comment: still same error..

Comment: run this `npm install enzyme enzyme-adapter-react-16 react-test-renderer --save`

Comment: Still same but I didn't change my test file.

Comment: `import {Link} from "react-router-dom";`
importing in this way solved my problem.

Comment: If you got the resolution, please update the title -  [closed/Resolved]